# On Win 10, on any browser, some sites can not reproduce sounds (only learning related websites affected?)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio

All right?

When using Chrome, Vivaldi or Edge, for example, I can play Youtube videos or other stuff and the sound is correctly played.

But, when I visit learning related websites it doesn't work! (actually checked on the following: translate.google , memrise and duolingo) In duolingo it plays not the words but the sounds when the words are correct, for example.

The sound image on the tab appears (the playing sound informative icon), in all the cases, but no sound is reproduced. I checked the drivers and they are updated. Also checked the Mixer and it's on the highest volume possible!

On Chrome (edit: on any browser when using translate.google), there's a peculiar thing that happens: when I type a word and wants to listen to its pronunciation and click on the sound button, it becomes a square while on the tab it appears as it should, so, no sound reproduced... then... it gets back to normal...

[Google's Translator situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNLMG.png)

Only on learning related websites??? If it helps: I am using GDATA as Internet Security...

How to solve this odd stuff? Anyone able to help, please?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: The square icon on Google Translate is not strange - it displays while the sound is playing, and clicking it will stop the playback. It looks strange to you only because you can't hear the corresponding sound.

Comment: As for your main question, a key difference is that in YouTube the audio is part of the video, so it would use different code of the browser and/or Windows than a pure audio playback. Also, it's compressed, but short pronunciation snippets are probably WAV format. More examples might help us narrow it down - are there videos that **don't** work, or audio that **does**? Try a podcast site, which would be compressed audio for sure (e.g. my church's MP3 messages are at https://abide-osaka.org/). Can you hear them?

Comment: So, I can not, no sound at all... Although I tried soundcloud and it worked! You are probably right on this then... format and stuff alike as you said can be the the real reason, but why? Dou you have any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: @OsakaWebbie, thanks for your help! As you can check, I was able to solve the issue after researching a bit and ending up finding the solution myself during the looking... :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I appreciate all the help I got!

For some reason, part of the sounds playback, including system sounds were working fine under the standard Windows' configuration. But for the browsers, specifically, I had to specify that it should be played on the speakers!

This config has to be set up on 'App Volume and Device Preferences'.

All done!! Thanks a lot!! :D